# In R, is there a simple way to convert two data frame columns for a formula with a grouping factor?

Tags: r

I have two vectors -- really columns in a data table -- and I want to compare the means with `wilcox_test` from `coin`.

With `wilcox.test` or t.test I can just do this:

```
wilcox.test(data$x,data$y)
```

But I need to use `wilcox_test`, which requires a formula like this:

```
wilcox_test(outcome ~ grp, data=myData)
```

I came up with this solution, which works:

```
outcome <- c(data$x,data$y)
grp <- c(c(rep(0, length(data$x))),c(rep(1, length(data$y))))
grp <-  as.factor(grp)
wilcox_test(outcome ~ grp)
```

But I'm wondering - is there a simpler way to do this? Or is this the best way?

Comment: Your solution is just fine. An alternative is something like stack(data.frame(x,y)) or using the reshape command.

Comment: I generally use `stack`, I think it's the easiest way, but there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack`. Here is an example

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)

#   x y
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 6

dat2 <- stack(dat)

#   values ind
# 1      1   x
# 2      2   x
# 3      3   x
# 4      4   y
# 5      5   y
# 6      6   y
```

Now, the outcome variable is in column `values` and the grouping variable is in column `ind`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use function **melt** from the package **reshape2**:

```
> library(reshape2)
> melt(data.frame(x=1:10,y=11:20))
Using  as id variables
   variable value
1         x     1
2         x     2
3         x     3
4         x     4
5         x     5
6         x     6
7         x     7
8         x     8
9         x     9
10        x    10
11        y    11
12        y    12
13        y    13
14        y    14
15        y    15
16        y    16
17        y    17
18        y    18
19        y    19
20        y    20
```

And then use `wilcox_test(value ~ variable,data=melt(data.frame(x=1:10,y=11:20)))`

Comment: I'm leaning towards using stack suggested in another answer, because it's a base R function and as far as I can tell it does exactly the same thing in my case, without needing to include another package. It seems like melt is needed when you have more columns. Is there some reason to use melt over stack in this case?